# How do I deal with a filename that starts with the hyphen (-) character?

Tags: linux, bash

Somehow, at some point, I accidentally created a file in my home directory named '-s'. It is about 500 kb and I have no idea if it contains important data or not. I cannot figure out any way to do *anything* with this file, because every command I use to try to view, copy, or move it interprets the filename as an argument.

I've tried putting it in quotes, escaping it with a backslash, a combination of the two, nothing seems to work.

Also, when I first posed this question to my coworkers, we puzzled over it for a while until someone finally overheard and asked "why don't you just rename it?" After I explained to him that cp and mv both think the filename is an argument so it doesn't work, he said "no, not from the command line, do it from Gnome." I sheepishly followed his advice, and it worked. HOWEVER I'm still interested in how you would solve this dilemma if you didn't have a window manager and the command line was the only option.

Comment: `rm -- -s`; the `--` is end-of-options

Comment: ...but this is a better question for [unix.se] than here.

Comment: I had the same with mv but can't see where this is documented when using man mv

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can refer to it either using `./-filename` or some command will allow you to put it after double dash:

```
rm -- -filename
```

Comment: Of course! Can't believe I didn't think of adding a path to the filename. Now I feel even sillier :-)

Comment: @histumness: same goes here :-)

Answer (score 20):

You can get rid of it with:

```
rm ./-s
```

The `rm` command (at least under Ubuntu 10.04) even tells you such:

```
pax@pax-desktop:~$ rm -w
rm: invalid option -- 'w'
Try `rm ./-w' to remove the file `-w'.
Try `rm --help' for more information.
```

The reason that works is because `rm` doesn't think it's an option (since it doesn't start with `-`) but it's still referring to the specific file *in the current directory*.

Answer (score 4):

You could use --, e.g.:

```
rm -- -file
```

Comment: correct but not generic, won't work with non-gnu and not even with all gnu utils

Comment: @sehe, it's POSIX-standardized, not a GNUism. `--long-args` are a GNUism, but this isn't that.

Comment: @sehe, ...see section 12.2 in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html, specifically guideline 10: **The first -- argument that is not an option-argument should be accepted as a delimiter indicating the end of options. Any following arguments should be treated as operands, even if they begin with the '-' character.** Because `rm`, `cat`, `mv`, etc. are all POSIX-standardized, they're required to comply except where the standard's documentation for that individual command indicates otherwise.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's good to know. In practice, one has to check, in my experience, but yeah not with the very core userland utilities.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun you could also use/abuse find.

```
find . -name "-s" -delete
```

or

```
find . -name "-s" -exec cat {} \;
```

Comment: The only way the `find . -name "-s" -exec cat {} \;` is different from `cat -s` (other than potential unwanted recursion) is that `find` runs `cat ./-s`. You could just tell the user to do that themselves without needing `find`, and many prior answers do.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I think you missed the point which is that find can be used to identify files with special characters without having to remember the specific escape sequences.

Comment: Indeed, I'm _still_ not seeing any kind of a point. Are you calling `./` an "escape sequence"? (It's a path to the directory the file is in, not an escape sequence). If someone doesn't know that `.` means "the current directory", and that `/` separates path elements... well, that's pretty basic knowledge that's generally expected for folks to know before they can be considered ready to use a UNIX-family operating system.

Comment: And if we're trying to make something easy to use for people who don't know the basics of how to use their operating system, I'd call a `find` command the opposite of that.

Comment: (And if you wanted to make that `find` command run in a bounded amount of time instead of getting slower the deeper the directory structure under the current working directory is, you'd want to add `-maxdepth 1` to the command line, making it _even more_ arcane).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I never suggested you should use this as any sort of optimal solution. Sometimes remembering a solution for a problem is more valuable than remembering the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

besides using `rm`, if you know a language, you can also use them. They are not affected by such shell warts.

Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -rfileutils -e 'FileUtils.rm("-s")'
```

or

```
$ ruby -e 'File.unlink("-s")'
```

Comment: `perl -e 'unlink "-s"'` (because Perl already knows about syscalls without loading anything)