# Delete dir with hyphen in name

Tags: linux, centos

I'm on CentOS 7.2 and I've somehow managed to create a folder called "-p". I can't seem to remove it now. I've tried the following:

`rmdir -p
rmdir "-p"
rmdir \-p
rmdir "\p"`

It's probably simple, but I'm struggling.

I guess worst case I'll move anything out of the parent folder and go for a `rm -rf`

Many thanks

EDIT: just figured out the command that did it (and has done it again)

`mkdir –p /etc/redis /var/redis`

...I don't even

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with a filename that starts with the hyphen (-) character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677558/how-do-i-deal-with-a-filename-that-starts-with-the-hyphen-character)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
rm ./-p
```

And depending on the `rm` used:

```
rm -- -p
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass foldernames starting with hypens to `mkdir` and `rmdir` after a "double hypen".
Here's an example:

```
$ ls -1
$ mkdir -- -p
$ ls -1
-p
$ rmdir -- -p
$ ls -1
$
```