# Removing file with name of an argument

Tags: bash

I was attempting to use the `xxd` command in bash, and used the `-r` argument, but forgot to add the in-file and out-file. I now have a useless file named `-r` and I cant remove it due to it being an argument for almost any command that I can think of that would be able to delete files.

Is there any other way for me to remove this file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I deal with a filename that starts with the hyphen (-) character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677558/how-do-i-deal-with-a-filename-that-starts-with-the-hyphen-character)

Answer (score 2):

To  remove  a  file whose name starts with a `-`, use:

```
rm -- -r
```

or

```
rm ./-r
```

---

`--` is used to signify the end of command options.